# Javascript 'value' property

Tags: javascript, html

I need to know which Javascript Elements have a "Value" property associated with them? According to MDN, paragraphs don't have "Value" property but have "textContent" property.
Is "Value" only used for manipulating text content of input type controls?

Comment: JavaScript does not have "elements" (unless you mean elements in an array). Do you mean HTML elements? Any documentation for the DOM will tell you what properties/attributes each type of HTML element has.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `value` attribute defines a default value which will be displayed in the element on page load. Form controls and some other html elements have this attribute (see list below).

The `value` **attribute** in HTML and the `value` **property** in JavaScript work differently for these controls. You can set the initial value with the value attribute, but the value property contains the actual value of the control. [Source](http://help.dottoro.com/ljpkovxr.php)

The `textContent` property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, **and all its descendants**. If you *set* the `textContent` property, any child nodes are removed and replaced by a single Text node containing the specified string.

To set or return the HTML content of an element, use the `innerHTML` property instead.

In HTML DOM, the `value` property sets or returns the value of the attribute:

- For `button`, `input` and `option` elements, the `value` attribute specifies the initial value of the element.
- For `li` elements, the `value` attribute sets the value of an ordered list item. The following list items will increment from that number.
- For `progress` elements, the `value` attribute specifies how much of the task has been completed.
- For `param` elements, the `value` attribute specifies the value of a  element.

HTML elements with `value` attribute: [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_value.asp) [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

- `button`
- `input`

  - `button`: type="button"
  - `checkbox`: type="checkbox"
  - `file`: type="file"
  - `hidden`: type="hidden"
  - `password`: type="password"
  - `radio`: type="radio"
  - `reset`: type="reset"
  - `submit`: type="submit"
  - `text`: type="text"
- `option`
- `li`
- `progress`
- `param`
- `meter`

Comment: Thanks Emre, very neatly explained... ( +1 for your reply)

Comment: Thank you. Please don't forget to accept as an answer if it is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Briefly:

All the elements which allow a user to type something in or select something, have a `value` property with js.

If the elements have just plain text, you can use`textContent` and `innerHTML` to get the plain text value

Answer (score 0):

`value` is a property of form field elements. Paragraphs (and other elements) have `textContent` and `innerHTML`.

It is closely coupled with a corresponding `value` *attribute* on the field - in other words, if one is updated, so is the other.