# Why document.getElementById().value returns a string even though its type is Number?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to make a tip calculator and the total variable returns a string because typeof bill is a string, why is it so, even though the text input box type is ***number***?

output("bill entered is 1000 and no of person is 1):- string
   150
   150
   1000150

```js
document.querySelector('#persons').addEventListener('change', (findresult));
document.querySelector('#bill').addEventListener('change', (findresult));
document.querySelector('#percent').addEventListener('change', (findresult));

function findresult() {
  var persons = document.getElementById('persons').value;
  var bill = document.getElementById('bill').value;
  var percent = document.getElementById('percent').value;
  // console.log(persons);
  console.log(typeof bill);
  // console.log(percent);
  var tip = (bill * percent) / 100;
  var tip_person = tip / persons;
  var total = bill + tip;
  console.log(tip);
  console.log(tip_person);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tip calcuator</h1><br>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="persons" placeholder="No of Persons"><br><br>
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="bill" placeholder="Bill"><br><br>
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="percent" placeholder="Tip%">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="result">
    <br>
    <p>Tip Per Person :</p>
    <p>TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the `value` property is defined as returning a string: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement. Note on that page there is a `valueAsNumber` property...

Comment: I doubt there is any publicly documented explanation of why the designers of that part of the DOM decided to make the `value` property of a number input be a string (like every other `value` property of every other form control) instead of a number. So answers to your question will be just a matter of opinion.

Comment: You can parse String to number  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Check out this reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217872/javascript-value-property

Comment: A `number` input has restrictions on what type of characters can be entered, and will only produce a `value` when the entry matches the pattern of a number, but it can have inputs that can't be represented as a JavaScript number. For example, `12341234123412341234123412341234`

Comment: @HereticMonkey, your solution fixed it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input value is a string instead of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27849944/input-value-is-a-string-instead-of-a-number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surround the `bill, percent` declaration values with [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to allow for decimals while converting the `value` String to a Number.

```js
var bill = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bill').value);
var percent = parseFloat(document.getElementById('percent').value);
```

You may allow decimals in the Number Input by using the `step` attribute and set it to `0.01`. This will affect the values created when using the up,down button on the Input.

```html
<input type="number" class="inputfield" id="bill" placeholder="Bill" step="0.01" >
```

```js
document.querySelector('#persons').addEventListener('change', (findresult));
document.querySelector('#bill').addEventListener('change', (findresult));
document.querySelector('#percent').addEventListener('change', (findresult));

function findresult() {
  var persons = document.getElementById('persons').value;
  // Use parseFloat to allow for decimals
  var bill = parseFloat(document.getElementById('bill').value);
  var percent = parseFloat(document.getElementById('percent').value);
  // console.log(persons);
  console.log(typeof bill);
  // console.log(percent);
  var tip = (bill * percent) / 100;
  var tip_person = tip / persons;
  var total = bill + tip;
  console.log(tip);
  console.log(tip_person);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Tip calcuator</h1><br>
  <div class="inputs">
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="persons" placeholder="No of Persons"><br><br>
    <!-- Allow cents to be allowed via the `step` attribute -->
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="bill" placeholder="Bill" step="0.01" ><br><br>
    <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="percent" placeholder="Tip%">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="result">
    <br>
    <p>Tip Per Person :</p>
    <p>TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

User parseInt(), it will convert string into number.

```
function findresult() {
  var persons = parseInt(document.getElementById('persons').value);
  var bill = parseInt(document.getElementById('bill').value);
  var percent = parseInt(document.getElementById('percent').value);
  // console.log(persons);
  console.log(bill);
  // console.log(percent);
  var tip = (bill * percent) / 100;
  var tip_person = tip / persons;
  var total = bill + tip;
  console.log(tip);
  console.log(tip_person);
  console.log(total);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Heretic Monkey, the input element has a property ***valueAsNumber*** and since the input type is always a number, we wouldn't have to worry about the parsing.
so we can use `document.getElementById('persons').valueAsNumber`

Also a few suggestions, it's always nice to break your code in smaller parts. Therefore separating the logic of fetching the input values and performing calculations separately will be a better approach and its not a good practice to call the DOM objects repeatedly.

For example, we can create a function for change event listener and read the event argument and update the necessary object of values,

```
document.querySelector('#persons').addEventListener('change', (update));
document.querySelector('#bill').addEventListener('change', (update));
document.querySelector('#percent').addEventListener('change', (update));

let values = {
    persons: 0,
    bill: 0,
    percent: 0,
}
function update(event) {
    values[event.currentTarget.id] = event.target.valueAsNumber;
    findresult();
}
```

Finally, you can read the values as follows,

```
var persons = values["persons"];
var bill = values["bill"];
var percent = values["percent"];
```

So putting all together,

```js
document.querySelector('#persons').addEventListener('change', (update));
document.querySelector('#bill').addEventListener('change', (update));
document.querySelector('#percent').addEventListener('change', (update));

let values = {
    persons: 0,
    bill: 0,
    percent: 0,
}
function update(event) {
    values[event.currentTarget.id] = event.target.valueAsNumber;
    findresult();
}

function findresult() {
  var persons = values["persons"];
  var bill = values["bill"];
  var percent = values["percent"];

  var tip = (bill * percent) / 100;
  var tip_person = tip / persons;
  var total = bill + tip;
  console.log(tip);
  console.log(tip_person);
  console.log(total);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1>Tip calcuator</h1><br>
    <div class="inputs">
        <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="persons" placeholder="No of Persons" step="0.01"><br><br>
        <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="bill" placeholder="Bill"><br><br>
        <input type="number" class="inputfield" id="percent" placeholder="Tip%">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="result">
        <br>
        <p>Tip Per Person :</p>
        <p>TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;:</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.