# jQuery: fetch the value from a table row by clicking a button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I've got a table on my page. Each row contains a  tag where the 'name' value is stored, but also a button.

```
<td>
  <div class="name">some_name</div>
  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success copyToClipboard">Copy</button>
</td>
```

And after clicking on that button I would like to get the value stored inside a div with class of name. So I've prepared a script:

```
$('.copyToClipboard').on('click', function(){
    console.log($(this).closest('td').children('.name')[0])
})
```

After clicking on button in my console I get this object:

```
<div class="name">some_name</div>
```

But if I want to fetch the value by using .val() method appended to the command above I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).children(...)[0].val is not a
> function

I'm not an expert in javascript/jQuery but I did something very similar and it worked correctly. How can I change my function in order to fetch stored value? Or maybe I should rewrite somehow my html structure to make it easier?

Comment: `div` tags hold text, not values.

Answer (score -1):

You need to recall jQuery after getting an indexed value:

```
$($(this).closest('td').children('.name')[0]).val();
```

Comment: You can not get the text content of a div by using `.val()`.

Comment: @Turnip so `.value` in JS should fail as well?

Comment: Yes. Divs do not a have a value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217872/javascript-value-property