# get value from html id javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have this:

```
     <% if(data.length){ 
            for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) { %>
      <tr>
        <td data-label="NAME" id="clientName" value="<%= data[i].NAME %>"><%= data[i].NAME %> <%= data[i].LASTNAME %></td>
        <td data-label="EMAIL" id="email" value="<%= data[i].EMAIL %>"><%= data[i].EMAIL %></td>
        <td data-label="PHONE NUM"><%= data[i].PHONENUMBER %></td>
        <td data-label="LOCATION"><%= data[i].LOCATION %></td>
        <td data-label="COMPANY NAME"><%= data[i].COMPANYNAME %></td>
        <td data-label="CODE" id="code" value="<%= data[i].CODE %>"><%= data[i].CODE %></td>


        <td data-label="SEND PAYMENT"><button onclick="confirmPayment()">SEND PAYMENT</button></td>  
        <script>
          function confirmPayment() {
           var email =  document.getElementById("email").value
           var name = document.getElementById("clientName").value
           var code = document.getElementById("code").value
           console.log(name)
           console.log(email)
           console.log(code)
           
           if (confirm('Are you sure you want to send Payment?'))
              {
                fetch('/sendPaymentCode', {
                method: 'POST', 
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
              body: JSON.stringify({
                email,
                name,
                code
              })
            })
              }
              else
              {
                console.log('Payment canceled.');
              }

            
          }
       
        </script>
      </tr>
      <% }
    }else{ %>
    <% } %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

I am basically trying to get the value of the users email, code, and name when I click send payment. However, it is not working, it is showing undefined in the console. There will be multiple users in the DB, so when it is being shown on the front end using a loop, but it is not logging anything when I try to get those values.

Is this the right way of doing it?

Comment: place the js code at the bottom of the page. This is not a correct html structure

Comment: You can't just declare the same function over and over (and expect your button to call the correct one). You're also putting the same `id`s multiple times in your table, again not supposed to happen in any way.

Comment: As for the solution: sending all that data back to the server is nonsense anyway; all you need is to uniquely identify the user from its button. Once you send along the id or email, you can just grab all other pertinent data from the db again. I'd put `data-email="<% data[i].EMAIL %>"` in the button. In a click handler assigned by a single script outside the loop to all buttons, you can read `this.dataset.email` and send that to the server.

Comment: Here's a very basic example demonstrating how to avoid massively duplicate and completely broken code: https://jsfiddle.net/70smwabv/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you for your input. I appreciate your way of going about it. I will be sure to try it this way

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `.innerText` instead of `.value` would've worked in theory :)

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use the [Element.getAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) method.

```
document.getElementById("email").getAttribute("value");
```

Here's a good answer about how the `value` attribute works between HTML and JS.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44217936/142410

I'll add there are some other issues with your code that you'll want to address, as pointed out in the comments, but as for why you're getting `undefined` it's because `td` elements do not have a `value` property.

Comment: Because they didn't ask for a code review. They asked why they're getting `undefined` when trying to access the `value` property of a `td` tag which simply doesn't exist. So this extreme arrogance of both your responses simply glossed over the core problem. If you had something to add, you could post an answer without talking down to someone, it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: Did you not see the comments I posted? I tried to help OP by pointing out the core problem with their approach and suggested an alternative to their value method. You ignored both the script in a loop and multiple id issues, implicitly suggesting to the OP that's all fine. Any future user who finds this will think that this is how its done, which is my primary concern whenever I post here, be it comment, answer or vote.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it did actually grab the value, but not specific to the user. I ended up using <input> tag for now, until I play around with a more concrete solution