# how to get the value from an xpath

Tags: javascript

I try to get the value from a XPath, but I always get "undefined" "null" as answer

that's the HTML code from the XPath:

```
<div id="HZiTMlXgXNBTLizpJUukKkfUJGAbZlYt" style="display:inline;">20</div>
```

and I tried it multiple times with:

```
var test1 = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/span/div', document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null).iterateNext().value;

var test2 = document.evaluate('/html/body/div[1]/section/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/h2/span/div', document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
```

does someone have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `value` by using:

```js
xpath = '/html/body/.../some_element';
val = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.value;
```

But

> [DIVs do not have a value property.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11238508/how-to-get-value-of-a-div-using-javascript/11238555)

So you need to use [another element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217872/javascript-value-property) with `value` property

Or use innerHTML to get `20` in your case:

```js
val = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
```